# Encoding issue in word document php generation

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ms-word

I am successfully generating a ms-word document in php. 
I am inserting in this document the html code I get from a rich text editor (tinyMCE). But I'm getting some extra unexpected caracters so I guess it is an encoding problem.

Here is the php code :

```
$content = $_GET['content'];
$filename = './cases/mydocument.htm';

$output = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>";
$output .= "<head><title>Mon document</title>";
$output .= "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
$output .= "<xml><w:WordDocument><w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom><w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/></w:WordDocument></xml>";
$output .= "<![endif]-->";
$output .= "<link rel=File-List href=\"mydocument_files/filelist.xml\">";
$output .= "<style><!-- ";
$output .= "@page";
$output .= "{";
$output .= "    size:21cm 29.7cmt;  /* A4 */";
$output .= "    margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; /* Margins: 2.5 cm on each side */";
$output .= "    mso-page-orientation: portrait;  ";
$output .= "    mso-header: url(\"mydocument_files/headerfooter.htm\") h1;";
$output .= "    mso-footer: url(\"mydocument_files/headerfooter.htm\") f1;  ";
$output .= "}";
$output .= "@page Section1 { }";
$output .= "div.Section1 { page:Section1; }";
$output .= "p.MsoHeader, p.MsoFooter { border: none; }";
$output .= "--></style>";
$output .= "</head>";
$output .= "<body>";
$output .= "<div class=Section1>";
$output .= $content;
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "</body>";
$output .= "</html>";

file_put_contents($filename, $output);

class mime10class
{
    private $data;
    const boundary='----=_NextPart_ERTUP.EFETZ.FTYIIBVZR.EYUUREZ';
    function __construct() { $this->data="MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"".self::boundary."\"\n\n"; }
    public function addFile($filepath,$contenttype,$data)
    {
        $this->data = $this->data.'--'.self::boundary."\nContent-Location: http://www.monsite.com/dev1/cases/".preg_replace('!\\\!', '/', $filepath)."\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\nContent-Type: ".$contenttype."\n\n";
        $this->data = $this->data.base64_encode($data)."\n\n";
    }
    public function getFile() { return $this->data.'--'.self::boundary.'--'; }
}

$doc = New mime10class();
$doc->addFile('mydocument.htm','text/html; charset="utf-8"',$output);

$output_encoded = $doc->getFile();

$filename = './cases/mydocument.doc';
file_put_contents($filename, $output_encoded);
```

For ex, my editor returns :

```
<p>test <em>italique</em></p>
```

I have checked and $content contains exactly this html part.
But when I perform the first file_put_content, I get this :

test Â italique

I have tried to apply utf8_encode on $output before the file_put_contents, then I get it even worst:

test Â,Ã italique

My notepad++ is configured in utf8 without BOM

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

whenever using tinymce, try to apply,

```
 stripslashes($_POST['content']);
```

Comment: and anyway the problem is not in the data transmission because when I echo $content I get the right text